# Kendo Upload control remove event has no response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-mvc, kendo-upload

I have a kendo upload control like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
    .Name("attachments")
    .Async(a => a
        .Save("UploadAsync", "Intel")
        .Remove("RemoveAsync", "Intel")
        .AutoUpload(true)
    )
    .Events(e => e
        .Success("onSuccessfulUpload")
        .Remove("onRemoveFile")
    )
    .Validation(v => v.AllowedExtensions(exts))
)
```

In the controller, its Save method is like this:

```
public ActionResult UploadAsync(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> attachments)
{
    string filename;
    // ... do things ...
    return Json(new { ImageName = filename }, "text/plain");
}
```

where the variable `filename` is assigned a value.

Its Remove method in the controller looks very similar:

```
public ActionResult RemoveAsync(string[] fileNames)
{
    string filename;
    // ... do things ...
    return Json(new { ImageName = filename }, "text/plain");
}
```

I verified that both controller methods *are* called correctly and the variable `filename` *is* assigned to in both cases.

The upload works as expected, and the Success event also works as expected. (The alert is simply for testing.)

```
function onSuccessfulUpload(e) {
    alert(e.response.ImageName);
}
```

The issue comes on removal of a file.

When I get to the Remove event, `e` does not have a `.response`.  It has `e.files` and `e.sender`, but no response.

```
function onRemoveFile(e) {
    alert(e.response);                    // undefined!
    alert(JSON.stringify(e.files));       // works, but does not have what I need
}
```

How do I access what the `RemoveAsync` method returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time poking around, I found the answer.

The key lay in the order of the events.  My first assumption was that the `Success` event was called after successful upload, and the `Remove` event was called after successful(?) removal. This was wrong.

The *actual* order of the events is:

- **JS `onUpload` > Controller `UploadAsync` > JS `onSuccess`**
- **JS `onRemoveFile` > Controller `RemoveAsync` > JS `onSuccess`**

#### My Solution:

I created two parallel arrays in javascript to represent the files uploaded in the client-side `e.files`, which contains uid's for each file, and the filenames created by the server-side controller method (which renames the files).

```
var fileUids = [];
var fileSaveNames = [];
```

I changed the `onSuccessfulUpload` function to this, when I discovered that there is an `e.operation` that specifies which operation was the successful one:

```
function onSuccess(e) {
    if (e.operation == "upload") {
        var filename = e.response.ImageName;
        var uid = e.files[0].uid;

        // add to the arrays
        fileUids.push(uid);
        fileSaveNames.push(filename)

        // ...
    }
    else if (e.operation == "remove") {
        var uid = e.files[0].uid;
        var saveIdx = fileUids.indexOf(uid);

        // remove from the arrays
        fileSaveNames.splice(saveIdx, 1);
        fileUids.splice(saveIdx, 1);

        // ...
    }
}
```

Then I updated the `removeFile` function, which I now knew was called *before* the method in the controller.

```
function removeFile(e) {
    var uid = e.files[0].uid;
    var idx = fileUids.indexOf(uid);
    e.data = { fileToRemove: fileSaveNames[idx] };
}
```

That last line, where I assign to `e.data`, was because of [this thread on the Telerik forums](http://www.telerik.com/forums/async-kendoupload-pass-custom-arguments-or-additional-data-to-mvc-controller#vJIokUu0iEmJF5UIMhkBSw), which has the following info:

> Solution: All that's needed it to define a function for the upload
> event and modify the "data" payload.
>
> Add the upload JS function to add a parameter "codeID" in my case.
>
> ```
> $("#files").kendoUpload({
>     [...]
>     upload: function (e) {
>         e.data = { codeID: $("#id").val() };
>     }
> });
> ```
>
> Now on the controller add the parameter and that's it.
>
> ```
> [HttpPost]
> public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, Guid codeID) { }
> ```

(Instead of being in the `Upload` event, mine is in the `Remove` event.)

I chose the parameter name `fileToRemove`, and now the new `RemoveAsync` method in the controller is as such:

```
public ActionResult RemoveAsync(string[] fileNames, string fileToRemove)
{
    string returnName = "";

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileToRemove))
    {
        // ... do things ...
    }

    return Json(new { ImageName = returnName }, "text/plain");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [remove](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload#events-remove) event doesn't provide this kind of data, so I see only a workaround to solve this.

You could try to put the result name to the headers, and you should be able to read the result:

```
// Controller
Response.AddHeader("ImageName", imageName); // before Json(...)

// View/JS
alert(e.headers['ImageName']);
```

I haven't tested that and I see a risk that that the `remove` event doesn't really read the async response, that would explain why the `response` object is not available.

In that case, you could try to use the following workaround: Don't call any Url on remove (or use some Action without any body, just a plain result) and inside of the event callback, execute `RemoveAsync` yourself.

```
// View/JS
function onRemoveFile(e) {
    $.post('@Html.Url("RemoveAsync", "Intel")', e.files, function(response) {
        alert(response);
    });
}
```

It's not pretty, but it should work and provide the results you need.

Comment: I looked at the order of the events: 
js onUpload > Controller.UploadAsync() > js onSuccess ...
js onRemoveFile > Controller.RemoveAsync > js onSuccess

Both go to the specific event before they go to the controller, then go to the Success event.  That's why I could get the JSON response after upload, simply because it was happening in that Success event.